# cmake minizip linking

Tags: c++, cmake

I need to add a dependency in my project to minizip, which is part of zlib. I have the library on my system, so I can do

```
target_link_libraries (myproject /usr/lib64/libminizip.so)
```

but I cannot find out what is the portable way to do it. I can find and link zlib itself with no problems using

```
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
```

but that does not link to the minizip library, as the `${ZLIB_LIBRARIES}` variable is set to `/usr/lib64/libz.so` and I need `/usr/lib64/libminizip.so`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One uses the package-config macros in this case.

First add

```
INCLUDE (FindPkgConfig)
```

then before the linking step we need to fill the UNZIP_LIBRARIES variable with the right information:

```
if (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
        PKG_CHECK_MODULES(UNZIP minizip)
endif (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
```

and finally, the linking step:

```
target_link_libraries (myproject ${UNZIP_LIBRARIES})
```